# Rails - how to create from in view that doesn't belong to same controller in Rails 5

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5

So basically I'm trying to implement order form that should be in products#show view which is a view that doesn't belong to OrderController.

P.S: the appropirate association between Order and Product models are many-to-many but, in my case it's one-to-many as the order contains only one product

So far I have write the following: 
**Order Model**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :comments

  # define scope for fetching products that have images
  scope :products_with_images, -> {where.not(image_url: nil)}
  scope :products_with_comments, -> {joins(:comments).order(created_at: :desc)}
end
```

**Order Controller**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
    @orders = Order.includes(:product, :user).where(user_id: current_user.id).all
  end
  def new
  end
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @order = @product.order.new(order_params)
    @order.user = current_user
    if @order.save
      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong!"
    end
  end
  def destroy
  end
  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :total)
  end
end
```

**Product Controller**

```
 def show
    @comments = @product.comments.order("created_at DESC")
    @order = Order.where('user_id= ?', current_user.id)
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @order = Order.new
  end
```

**views/orders/_new_order.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @orders) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :total, value: @product.price %>
<%= f.submit "Order", class: "btn btn-info btn-lg my-2" %>
<% end %>
```

**views/products/show.html.erb**

```
  # some code related to product show here and render new_order partial view
  <%= render 'orders/new_order' %>
```

**Routes file:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # if user is signed in the root_path will be products#index
  authenticated :user do
    root 'products#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end
  root 'static_pages#index'
  get '/index', to: 'static_pages#index'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/featured', to: 'static_pages#featured'
  post 'static_pages/thank_you'

  # devise_for :users
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register'}

  resources :users

  resources :products do
    resources :comments
  end

  # get '/products/:id', to: 'products#show'
  resources :orders, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  # resources :orders, except: [:new, :edit, :update]
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

*So when I'm trying to add new order in products#show page I get this error from server console:*

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/products/1")
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

We can render form, from any controller to another controller as you have used, don't need any route for that. Issue was a typo error in instance variable, follow as below

Product Controller

```
def show
  @comments = @product.comments.order("created_at DESC")
  @orders = Order.where('user_id= ?', current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: Still got the same error when try to POST new order request!


`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/products/1")`